# Eclipse - XML Schema Definition

Tags: xml, eclipse

Looking at http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd#xsd. We have the text:

"The XML Schema Definition is a reference library that provides an API for use with any code that examines, creates or modifies W3C XML Schema (standalone or as part of other artifacts, such as XForms or WSDL documents)."

From this, I understand that I can write a java class that uses the 'XML Schema Definition' API to create an XML file, and that this created XML file is one that I can then feed into tools like EMF and so on.  Presuming my understanding is correct (and if it isn't, please tell me how), where would I go to find a 'hello world' type example of such a java class?

Answer (score 3):

The XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
     jxb:version="2.0">

  <xsd:element name="Greetings" type="GreetingListType"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="GreetingListType">
     <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="Greeting" type="GreetingType"
             maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="GreetingType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Text" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="language" type="xsd:language"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Java class:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import hello.*;

public class Hello {

private ObjectFactory of;
private GreetingListType grList;

public Hello(){
    of = new ObjectFactory();
    grList = of.createGreetingListType();
}

public void make( String t, String l ){
    GreetingType g = of.createGreetingType();
    g.setText( t );
    g.setLanguage( l );
    grList.getGreeting().add( g );
}

public void marshal() {
    try {
        JAXBElement<GreetingListType> gl =
            of.createGreetings( grList );
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "hello" );
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.marshal( gl, System.out );
    } catch( JAXBException jbe ){
        // ...
    }
}
```

}

Example:

```
Hello h = new Hello();
h.make( "Bonjour, madame", "fr" ); 
h.make( "Hey, you", "en" ); 
h.marshal();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Greetings>
<Greeting language="fr">
<Text>Bonjour, madame</Text>
</Greeting>
<Greeting language="en">
<Text>Hey, you</Text>
```

Comment: That's great - but I'm struggling a little with of.createGreetings - can't seam to find a way to create the right format :(

Comment: That could be because of the format of the .XSD itself. Did you just copy and paste it? You should verify that the format is correct.Try XML spy or XML editor to verify that it is.

Comment: Pefect - but I can't appear to give you the bounty - where's the button gone?

Comment: No problems mate ;). I think it already expired when I answered you.